# SVG change x,y (0,0) top left to the center of my image

Tags: svg

How to change the center of an svg file ?

Actually when I set X or Y attributes of my svg image, these coordinates are based to the top left corner of my image and I want to set these by the center of my image.

Any idea ?

PS: I use an image with .svg extension

Answer (score 12):

In your SVG, set the `viewBox` to `-{width / 2}, -{height / 2}, width, height`. Given a width of 600 and a height of 400, your SVG would include `viewBox="-300 -200 600 400"`.

**[JSFiddle example using the HTML5 logo](http://jsfiddle.net/fezDu/4/)**

Comment: Your JSfiddle doesn't work ? the element is not centered
I'm on chrome

Comment: @LoryHuz It works on Chrome, but I don't think the demo did a good job explaining what's happening. I updated the JSFiddle to include a `<circle/>` element at the origin (`0, 0`) in both graphics.

Comment: This is brilliant. It did simply my code so much thanks

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the *width* of the `svg` element is `W` and its *height* is `H`.
You can use the following pattern:

```
<svg width="W" height="W">
    <g transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 W/2 H/2)">
        ...
    </g>
</svg>
```

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" style="border: 1px solid gray;">
    <g transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 100 100)">
        <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="25" fill="red"></circle>
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="10" fill="blue"></circle>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: If `width` or `height` is unknown, you can call `offsetwidth` on the svg element.